# Clion прерывает выполнение проекта

Tags: консоль, clion

При выполнении этого когда и вводе Numbers = 20, Clion произвольно завершает выполнение. Может вывести первые 4 символа таблицы. Может выполнить до 17 пункта а может до 13. Системы никакой нету. В настройках консоли ничего нет. Причём если через дебаг запустить в консоли windows то всё работает нормально, до конца.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <Iomanip>

using namespace std;

int Number,iter;
double fx1,fx2,xiter,h,Upper,Lower;

int main() {
cout << "Enter lower border: " << "\n";
cin >> Lower;
cout << "Enter upper border: " << "\n";
cin >> Upper;
cout << "Enter number of steps: " << "\n";
cin >> Number;

if (Number <= 0) {
    cout << "ERROR:Number of steps should be greater than 0!";
    return 1;
} else if (Lower > Upper) {
    cout << "ERROR:Lower border should be less than upper!";
    return 1;
}

h = (Upper - Lower) / Number;
cout << char(218) << char(196);
for (int j = 0;j < 33;j++) {
    cout << char(196);
}
cout << char(191) << "\n";

if (Upper == Lower) {
    cout << char(179) << setw(10) <<setprecision(2) << "1" << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << 2 - cos(Lower) << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << exp(-pow(Lower,2)) << char(179) << "\n";
} else {

    do {
        iter++;
        xiter = ((iter * h) + Lower);
        fx1 = 2 - cos(xiter);
        fx2 = exp(-pow(xiter, 2));
        cout << char(179) << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << iter << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << fx1 << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << fx2 << char(179) << "\n";
        if (iter != Number) {
            cout << char(195);
            for (int j = 0; j < 34; j++) {
                cout << char(196);
            }
            cout << char(180) << "\n";
        }
    } while (h * iter < abs(Upper - Lower));

}
cout << char(192);
for (int j = 0; j < 34; j++) {
    cout << char(196);
}
cout << char(217);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте через внутреннее `Registry...` выключить свойство `run.process.with.pty`. По Windows иногда чудит.